# JavaScript binary operators

Tags: javascript, operators

Working on a WebGL project and I am looking over code from a class example. In one of the loops this code was given:

```
var c = (((i & 0x8) == 0) ^ ((j & 0x8)  == 0));
```

The variables `i` and `j` go up to a certain value in a for loop. What does this statement mean? Does this make sure that the variable `c` is in hexadecimal form?

```
var texSize = 64; 
var image1 = new Array(); 
for (var i =0; i<texSize; i++) 
    image1[i] = new Array(); 
for (var i =0; i<texSize; i++) 
    for ( var j = 0; j < texSize; j++) 
        image1[i][j] = new Float32Array(4); 
for (var i =0; i<texSize; i++) 
    for (var j=0; j<texSize; j++) 
    { 
        var c = (((i & 0x8) == 0) ^ ((j & 0x8) == 0)); 
        image1[i][j] = [c, c, c, 1]; 
    }
```

Comment: Not an answer, but you should consider using `===` operator instead of `==` in JavaScript. Especially when you are not sure of what you are doing as operation.

Comment: Important note: "hexadecimal" has absolutely nothing to do with this. It's just a notational convention. Also, variables "are" not "in hex" or not -- they contain *a number* (or another type of value such as `bool` or `string`, but "hex" supposes you are talking about numerical contents).

Comment: @Aracthor: `==` is totally fine when values of the same type are compared, as is the case here.

Comment: See also [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549780/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

SMchrohan's answer is correct. The code is basically making a checkerboard texture.

The `?? & 0x8` means it that expression will be true when bit 3 (0,1,2,3) is true. bit 3 in binary is true every other set of 8 values (0-7 it's false, 8-15 it's true, 16-23 it's false, etc).

Then the code takes the opposite of that with == 0.

It does it for both `i` and `j`.

The `^` means *exclusive-or* which is true when both parts are the different (true, false or false, true) and false when they are both the same (false, false, or true, true). Because `^` is a bitwise operator both values are first converted to integers so `false` becomes 0 and `true` becomes 1. The 2 int values then have their bits *exclusive-or*ed so

```
0 ^ 0 = 0
1 ^ 0 = 1
0 ^ 1 = 1
1 ^ 1 = 0
```

that means each entry in `image1` is either `[0, 0, 0, 1]` or `[1, 1, 1, 1]`

here's some code to plot it

```js
var texSize = 64; 
var image1 = new Array(); 
for (var i =0; i<texSize; i++) 
    image1[i] = new Array(); 
for (var i =0; i<texSize; i++) 
    for ( var j = 0; j < texSize; j++) 
        image1[i][j] = new Float32Array(4); 
for (var i =0; i<texSize; i++) 
    for (var j=0; j<texSize; j++) 
    { 
        var c = (((i & 0x8) == 0) ^ ((j & 0x8) == 0)); 
        image1[i][j] = [c, c, c, 1]; 
    }

// lets plot it

var ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
document.body.appendChild(ctx.canvas);
ctx.canvas.width = texSize;
ctx.canvas.height = texSize;

for (var i =0; i<texSize; i++) 
    for (var j=0; j<texSize; j++) 
    { 
        var c = image1[i][j][0]
        ctx.fillStyle = c ? "red" : "yellow";
        ctx.fillRect(i, j, 1, 1);
    }
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<body></body>
```

Note that the code doesn't appear to make much sense. It says `texSize` so it seems to be making a texture but it's making one `Float32Array` per pixel (the line that says)

```
image1[i][j] = new Float32Array(4);
```

and then it's replacing each of those individual Float32Arrays with a JavaScript native array on this line

```
image1[i][j] = [c, c, c, 1];
```

Which makes the Float32Array line useless.

On top of that I have no idea what an array or arrays of 1 pixel Float32Arrays is good for. You can't upload it like that to WebGL.

Normally I'd make one Uint8Array for the entire texture like this

```
var texSize = 64; 
var pixels = new Uint8Array(texSize * texSize * 4);

for (var i =0; i<texSize; i++)  {
    for (var j=0; j<texSize; j++) { 
        var c = (((i & 0x8) == 0) ^ ((j & 0x8) == 0)); 
        var p = c ? 255 : 0;
        var offset = (i * texSize + j) * 4;
        pixels[offset + 0] = p;  // red
        pixels[offset + 1] = p;  // green
        pixels[offset + 2] = p;  // blue
        pixels[offset + 3] = 255;// alpha
    }

}
```

Or I'd use the 2D canvas API to make the texture

without some context though I don't know what the final purpose of the code is.

Comment: I think c actually comes out as an it...surprisingly (to me), `true ^ true` is returning 0, not false. Regardless, yes...this code is pretty opaque. OP shouldn't feel bad about being confused...whoever wrote this seems to have gone out of their way to do things oddly.

Comment: Oh, interesting. You're right. `^` is a bitwise operator so it will coerce the value to ints. Will fix

Answer (score 1):

`&` is bitwise and.

`^` is bitwise xor.

`0x8` is the hex expression of the integer 8.

`c` will be 1 if either `i` or `j` BUT NOT BOTH have a 1 in their 4th bit - that is, a bitwise and with 0x8 (binary 1000) returns 0.

To walk through this a little more:

`i & 0x8` will return either 0 (if the value of i has a 0 in bit 4) or 8 (if it has a 1 in that position).

`(i & 0x8) == 0` will be either true or false.

`(((i & 0x8) == 0) ^ ((j & 0x8)  == 0))` will be 1 if either `((i & 0x8) == 0)` or `((j & 0x8)  == 0)` is true, or 0 if both are false OR both are true.

Comment: So the var c is a boolean value? Here is the rest of the code that might help make a little more sense:  var texSize =64;                                                                                     var image1 = new Array()
    for (var i =0; i<texSize; i++)  image1[i] = new Array();
    for (var i =0; i<texSize; i++) 
        for ( var j = 0; j < texSize; j++) 
           image1[i][j] = new Float32Array(4);
    for (var i =0; i<texSize; i++) for (var j=0; j<texSize; j++) {
        var c = (((i & 0x8) == 0) ^ ((j & 0x8)  == 0));
  image1[i][j] = [c, c, c, 1];
    }